# How to resolve MongoBulkWriteException while updating an existing record?

Tags: mongodb, grails, grails-orm, grails-3.3

Hi while trying to save an existing record in DB i am getting **MongoBulkWriteException**

Bulk write operation error on server db2:27017. Write errors:

> [BulkWriteError{index=0, code=16837, message='Cannot update 'version'
>   and 'version' at the same time', details={ }}]. . Stacktrace follows:
>
> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null     at
>   org.grails.core.DefaultGrailsControllerClass$ReflectionInvoker.invoke(DefaultGrailsControllerClass.java:211)
>     at
>   org.grails.core.DefaultGrailsControllerClass.invoke(DefaultGrailsControllerClass.java:188)
>     at
>   org.grails.web.mapping.mvc.UrlMappingsInfoHandlerAdapter.handle(UrlMappingsInfoHandlerAdapter.groovy:90)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPut(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
>     at
>   grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.RestLogoutFilter.doFilter(RestLogoutFilter.groovy:82)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
>     at
>   grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.UpdateRequestContextHolderExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(UpdateRequestContextHolderExceptionTranslationFilter.groovy:64)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.groovy:54)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.RestAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RestAuthenticationFilter.groovy:139)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter.doFilter(MutableLogoutFilter.groovy:64)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.SecurityRequestHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityRequestHolderFilter.groovy:58)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
>     at
>   org.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:77)
>     at
>   org.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:62)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
>   com.mongodb.MongoBulkWriteException: Bulk write operation error on
>   server db2:27017. Write errors: [BulkWriteError{index=0, code=16837,
>   message='Cannot update 'version' and 'version' at the same time',
>   details={ }}].    at
>   com.mongodb.connection.BulkWriteBatchCombiner.getError(BulkWriteBatchCombiner.java:176)
>     at
>   com.mongodb.connection.BulkWriteBatchCombiner.throwOnError(BulkWriteBatchCombiner.java:205)
>     at
>   com.mongodb.connection.BulkWriteBatchCombiner.getResult(BulkWriteBatchCombiner.java:146)
>     at
>   com.mongodb.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation$1.call(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:188)
>     at
>   com.mongodb.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation$1.call(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:168)
>     at
>   com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnectionSource(OperationHelper.java:426)
>     at
>   com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnection(OperationHelper.java:417)
>     at
>   com.mongodb.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation.execute(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:168)
>     at
>   com.mongodb.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation.execute(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:74)
>     at com.mongodb.Mongo.execute(Mongo.java:845)    at
>   com.mongodb.Mongo$2.execute(Mongo.java:828)   at
>   com.mongodb.MongoCollectionImpl.bulkWrite(MongoCollectionImpl.java:301)
>     at
>   com.mongodb.MongoCollectionImpl.bulkWrite(MongoCollectionImpl.java:248)
>     at
>   org.grails.datastore.mapping.mongo.MongoSession.flush(MongoSession.java:197)
>     at
>   org.grails.datastore.mapping.mongo.AbstractMongoSession.flush(AbstractMongoSession.java:74)
>     at
>   org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormInstanceApi.doSave(GormInstanceApi.groovy:367)
>     at
>   org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormInstanceApi$_save_closure5.doCall(GormInstanceApi.groovy:179)
>     at
>   org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.DatastoreUtils.execute(DatastoreUtils.java:319)
>     at
>   org.grails.datastore.gorm.AbstractDatastoreApi.execute(AbstractDatastoreApi.groovy:40)
>     at
>   org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormInstanceApi.save(GormInstanceApi.groovy:178)
>     at
>   org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEntity$Trait$Helper.save(GormEntity.groovy:151)
>     at
>   com.lakshya.PermissionController$$EQo2Eywh.$tt__update(PermissionController.groovy:77)
>     at
>   grails.gorm.transactions.GrailsTransactionTemplate$2.doInTransaction(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:94)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133)
>     at
>   grails.gorm.transactions.GrailsTransactionTemplate.execute(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:91)
>     at
>   grails.gorm.transactions.GrailsTransactionTemplate$2.doInTransaction(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:94)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133)
>     at
>   grails.gorm.transactions.GrailsTransactionTemplate.execute(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:91)
>     at
>   org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:738)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:85)
>     at
>   com.ratetag.aspect.PerformanceMonitorAspect.profileWeb(PerformanceMonitorAspect.groovy:79)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:629)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:618)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:70)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673)
>     ... 40 common frames omitted

Comment: The exception suggests you may be trying to update a  `version` field twice in the same update: `'Cannot update 'version' and 'version' at the same time`. What is the update command you are running? If your code isn't doing anything that directly references the `version` field, please include the specific versions of MongoDB driver and server you are using.

Comment: Hi @Stennie , this is the code i am using 

'org.grails.plugins:mongodb:6.1.5' - mongo plugin 

Server i am using Tomcat


    def update(Permission permissionInstance) {
        if (permissionInstance == null) {
            notFound()
            return
        }

        if (permissionInstance.hasErrors()) {
            respond permissionInstance.errors,model:[permissionInstance:permissionInstance], view:'/administration/permission/edit'
            return
        }

        permissionInstance.save(flush:true)

Comment: @KapilArora, did you ever figure out what was happening with this? I'm experiencing the same issue on the same version of grails and mongo driver. The odd thing in my case is that it's occurring with a criteria query, so I'm not even trying to update or write anything.